# Travel to Schengen zone with France as point of entry from UK

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, schengen-visas, applications, itineraries

I am an Indian national living in UK on a work visa (ICT tier 2) with my wife who is also an Indian national on a dependent visa. We want to travel to Schengen zone on a short term tourist visa, entering through France and spending 2-3 days in each country (France-Belgium-Netherlands-Germany-Czech-Italy-Spain-France). Should we apply through French embassy? 
I visited the French visa website but it seems that it is only for French visa and not for Schengen Visa. Please help.

Comment: If there's no country that is clearly the main destination, apply to the country of your point of entry: i.e. France. That said, your proposed itinerary looks very ambitious. Travelling through the Low Countries won't be a problem, but travelling from Germany, through the Czech Republic to Italy and Spain will entail many hours in a car or in airports. It can be done but you won't see much. Consider an itinerary focussing on Northern Europe this time, and save Southern Europe for later. That might give you a clearer idea of where your main destination is.